# loading html code with html

Tags: javascript, html, embed, loader

I want javascript to load a html code so it can be embedded in a page, all I get is the raw html code without being compiled.

```
<script>
document.write('http://www.example.com/index.php?title=Media:Object4&action=raw&ctype=html')
</script>
```

It contains the html coding inside and I want it to embed in pages so I can share with other websites.

Comment: First HTML code does not *run*. Second there is *no* compilation anywhere whatsoever.

Comment: You could look into AJAX, but that is very hard if you want to request data from another domain.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get the HTML from that URL and embed it in the page? JavaScript can't do that for security reasons, but if you're using PHP server-side you can use:

```php
echo file_get_contents("http://..........");
```

Or you can use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://........" />
```

Answer (score 2):

document.write - adds text to the document - it **does not** fetch documents from the web.

However, you can use the [object tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp).

It should look something like that:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com/index.php?title=Media:Object4&action=raw&ctype=html" style="width:100%; height:100%"></object>
```

Additionally, if the page that you are fetching is on the same domain, you can use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to fetch it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to make this work, sort of, is by using `<iframe`>:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/index.php?title=Media:Object4&action=raw&ctype=html"></iframe>
```

If you want to load it inside a particular container, you have to perform a web request using JavaScript; jQuery example:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    $('#container').load('http://www.example.com/index.php?title=Media:Object4&action=raw&ctype=html');
</script>
```

If the remote URL is not in the same domain, you need to use a proxy:

```
<script>
    $('#container').load('/path/to/myproxy.php', {
        url: 'http://www.example.com/index.php?title=Media:Object4&action=raw&ctype=html'
    });
</script>
```

Then your PHP code could look like:

```
<?php

if (parse_url($_POST['url'], PHP_URL_HOST) === 'www.example.com') {
    echo file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
}
```

Comment: Lets say I have my page and I want the script to load another html script, all that above still gives me the text instead of it being compiled.

Comment: @user2056671 You have JavaScript on the remote page that needs to be run as well?

Comment: Yes, I want it do to just that.

Comment: @user2056671 You can really only do that inside `<iframe>`; if you want to load a remote JavaScript file you could do `<script src="/path/to/remote/script">` either directly or via proxy.